# It is possible to know if users are logged in and logged out on ms crm 4.0?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i want to do little chat on ms crm 4.0 and i want to know if i can to catch all users that currently loggedin into ms crm 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Not natively. You could do a number of things to maintain a list of users who have recently made requests to CRM, but that's not quite the same.

Comment: really? haven't there any solution for that? i think that count the requests to the crm system it a bad idea.. because how to catch users that are logged in but doesn't send any requests?

Comment: There is no real "logged in" in MSCRM. Users that don't send any requests are not working with the system, which means they're most probably not even looking at it and thus wouldn't notice the chat anyway.